# Changing subfigure numbering style in \ref

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, thesis, books, report

I have been formatting thesis which is based on report class and the latex code has numerous subfigures; whenever I use \ref to reference a subfigure, it shows up like 1.2a style where 1=chapter no., 2= figure number, and a=subfigure.

But is like to appear the specific figure reference style as 1.2(a).

How to do it?  Thank you in advance for your help. I used the following code.

```
\usepackage{subfig} % used package

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{imgs/ch_3_fig_5_1.png}\label{ch:3_fig:5_1}}%a
\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{imgs/ch_3_fig_5_2(2).png}\label{ch:3_fig:5_2}}%b
\caption{(a) caption 1, (a) caption 2.}
\label{ch:3_fig:5_1:2} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please tell us which package you employ to create the subfigures: `subcaption`, `subfig`, or `subfigure`. Please also edit your posting to show the code for a representative subfigure.

Comment: I have found an easy solution.  \ \ref{fig label}(\subref*{subfigure label}). I got the help from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21574